# Publish DB-Project (SSDT) with FileStream columns to LocalDB

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localdb, sql-server-data-tools

i have a dbproject with a table that has a fileStream column.

I can deploy/publish this project to my DB-Server (sql server 2014). 
For Testing I want also publish this project to my localdb (Visual Studio 2015).
But i get the error in the publish process, that FileStream is not supported in the LocalDB.

Are there any tricks to disable/modify the FileStream column for the publishing? 
I don't need the FileStream feature in the LocalDB. I need only the DB Schema.

Regards

Comment: Why not use sqlexpress 2016 sp1?

Comment: Hi, it was not necessary in the past. The localdb was enough. Maybe its time to switch to the full express version. But before I give up and switch with all my teammates we find a solution for the contextual publish of the project :/

Comment: @user1481065 Do you have some update to this issue? We have the same problem with `FileStream` and publishing to a `LocalDb`.